# Error in encoding date format to use it in json in swift3

Tags: json, swift3

```
let dateFormatter1 : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

let date1 = Date()
let myString1 = dateFormatter1.string(from: date1)

let data1 = myString1.data(using: .utf8)

self.dateString1 = String(data: data1!, encoding: .utf8)!

func postYumms() {
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

    if let context = delegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext{
       let person = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Mydata", into: context) as! Mydata
       let newString = self.timeString.replacingOccurrences(of: "", with: "/")
       let dateescapedString = self.dateString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:.urlHostAllowed)
       let timeescapedString = newString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:.urlQueryAllowed)
       print(timeescapedString!)

       let joinString = dateescapedString! + "+" + newString

       let parameters = "Post_id=\(self.ID)" + "&Post_type=\(self.PTYPE)" + "&Created_by=\(self.UID)" + "&Created_on=\(self.dateString1)"
       print(parameters)

       let url = "http://shiftu.org/api/zTimeline/post_like?"

       let upara = url + parameters

       print(upara)

       Alamofire.request(upara, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
           switch(response.result) {
           case .success(_):
               if response.result.value != nil{
                   print(response.result.value!)
               }
               break

           case .failure(_):
               print(response.result.error!)
               break
           }
    }
}
```

it showing error like

`invalidURL("http://shiftu.org/api/zTimeline/post_like?Post_id=8172&Post_type=1&Created_by=3234&Created_on=18/Jul/2017 12:14:02"`

please , some one help me

Comment: Why are you encoding the date string as .utf8? These 2 lines seem unnecessary to me: `let data1 = myString1.data(using: .utf8); 
self.dateString1 = String(data: data1!, encoding: .utf8)!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a string representation of a date with spaces in it as a URL query parameter without URL encoding the string.
You actually do the encoding, but then don't use the encoded strings anywhere.

Just changing this line should solve your problem:

`let parameters = "Post_id=\(self.ID)" + "&Post_type=\(self.PTYPE)" + "&Created_by=\(self.UID)" + "&Created_on=\(joinString)"`

Comment: Hi David ,   I have edited the line as you have mentioned.Bu it i showing some error as follows                    
                                                      
    http://shiftu.org/api/zTimeline/post_like?Post_id=8172&Post_type=1&Created_by=3234&Created_on=18%2FJul%2F2017+14:54:39
responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}))

Comment: It seems like your API is returning an invalid JSON response. Check what happens if you decode the response manually using the built in `JSONSerialization` framework or check the API response in another program, for example in Postman.

Comment: When i am trying it on postman, it returns a successful response. I thing the problem is in the date format i am passing . Because there is a space between the time and date .But i am unable to decode it

Comment: If it works in Postman, double check if your date format is the same in Postman and in Swift. You can also check the proposed Swift code generated by Postman mirroring your Postman request by clicking the Code button in Postman and changing the language to Swift.

Comment: postman showing                                                                                                     let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://shiftu.org/api/zTimeline/post_like?Post_id=64&Post_type=7&Created_by=2133&Created_on=18%20Jul%202017%2015%3A34%3A23")                                                                                                         so , how to encode the date format as    18%20Jul%202017%2015%3A34%3A23

Comment: `"18/Jul/2017 12:14:02".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlUserAllowed)` returns `""18%2FJul%2F2017%2012%3A14%3A02""`, which escapes all special characters in your detesting (__", ,:__), so I think it should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks David for your help

Comment: @TapanRaut no worries, glad I could help. If you found my answer helpful, please accept and upvote it.